# Cannot install wireless network USB adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

A few weeks ago I ordered this [this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XCJF9LZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) USB wifi stick from Amazon.de.

I have a DUAL boot with both windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 OS on my desktop computer. The driver works directly on the windows OS without any installation whatsoever. 
On ubuntu however, it doesn't recognize the adapter at all as it keeps saying "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" in the settings.

I got a CD-rom and a small instruction manual for installation of the driver for each platform.
The instructions refer to the driver download link in case the CD-rom is futile, which I used. 
The url is https : // bit.ly / 2IXCf8i (without spaces).

This installation provides a folder with installation instructions of its own and a LINUX folder with three subfolder options: RTL8811 RTL8812 and RTL8814. I'm not sure what the chipset of this adapter is though, so I tried to install them all. But everytime I try to install them, I get an error as follows:
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:284: recipe for target '/home/****/20190622/LINUX/RTL8814/RTL8814AU_Linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031/driver/rtl8814AU_linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/****/20190622/LINUX/RTL8814/RTL8814AU_Linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031/driver/rtl8814AU_linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1614: recipe for target '_module_/home/****/20190622/LINUX/RTL8814/RTL8814AU_Linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031/driver/rtl8814AU_linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/****/20190622/LINUX/RTL8814/RTL8814AU_Linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031/driver/rtl8814AU_linux_v4.3.21.1_24835.20171031] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic'
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

The same thing happens either via `sudo make` or sudo `./install.sh`.

I'm not sure how to proceed at this point, as I feel I've tried all the possibilities till now.
Does anyone know how to install the driver for this USB wifi adapter?

Let me know if I need to post any more info.

Comment: Please check your computer manufacturer for the version of that device your system uses so you know which to install!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I asked this question, I found that a user posted on the Amazon product page what driver to install. The github page for the driver is to be found on
[here](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959).

With **dkms**, the following instructions worked for me:

```
cd rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Unbelievable that I couldn't get a working driver for so long before!.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the latest drivers from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`

Though the repo name have `RTL8812AU` in it, the repo description does say, `RTL8812AU/21AU and RTL8814AU drivers`.

As per the repo, this is how you can install the drivers using DKMS method:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Your USB WiFi adapter should be working now.