# Ubuntu driver for a tp-link wifi adapter

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, adapter

I have a problem with making a wifi adapter TL-WDN6200 by tp-link work under Ubuntu 16.04.

I had been using an rtl8812au driver for a year. Once in a while it stopped working and I had to repeat the entire installation procedure over again: make, make install, modprobe rtl8815au. After a few attempts it worked again. Now the situation is different. The same procedure does not work no matter hiw many times I repeat it. I tried to download other drivers from the Internet to no avail.

Ubuntu has successfully detected the adapter.  Moreover, I can see the list of available wifi networks. However, when I try to connect to one, it does not connect. Other devices connect to the same network without an issue.

What am I possibly doing wrong? Is it a driver problem or a hardware problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `uname -a; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @bored if the RTL8812AU were working for you, you could try installing the drivers from aircrack-ng GitHub repo as described in here: `https://askubuntu.com/a/1198198/928088`

Comment: “stopped working” is most likely caused by kernel update,  you can try boot to some previous version (in grub, select the option with `advanced` and choose an older kernel)